# python3 code doesn't write files when opened with rc.local

Tags: python-3

i coded a small datalogger in python3 that gets readings from an Arduino and stores them locally. The code works if i open it manually, but as soon as i reboot and code runs from rc.local it stops writing new files. code is running, i can see it through `systemctl status rc-local` and it also is getting data from arduino (i have multiple echos and see everything that flows inbetween). i dont know what to look for. i'm running it with `sudo python3 /home/pi/mycodedir &` both from rc.local and terminal. when its running in terminal everything's fine, when from the rc.local everything's still fine just it does not write files. everything else (or at least what i've checked so far) is working.

> Edit

i tried `cron` as well but no luck. exactly same behaviour.
im using pickle to dump the data file

```
def saveReadings(self):
        for sensor in self.sensors:
            if(sensor.readings!=[]):
                filename="{2}readings/{0}/{1}.{3}sj".format(sensor.id,
                                                            sensor.last_comm.strftime("%d-%m-%Y/%H%M%S"),
                                                            sensor.type,
                                                            "t" if sensor.type=="tilt" else "c" if sensor.type=="crack" else "u")
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                with open(filename,"wb") as file:
                    self.esrlock.acquire()
                    pickle.dump([sensor.id,sensor.readings],file)
                    self.esrlock.release()
                    sensor.readings=[]
```

> Fix...

it was my fault not thinking about it. `cron` as well as `rc.local` run code as root so when i was wrote to save readings at `"location/file.type"` it was not saving it where i subconsciously thought, at `"~/mycodedir/location/file.type"`, but rather at `"/location/file.type"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an initial observation, is `/home/pi/mycodedir` actually the name of your executable file?... I ask because it *looks* like it may be a directory name instead. If that's not the problem, read on:

[`rc.local` is *deprecated*](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=rc.local+is+deprecated&atb=v278-1&ia=web). You could run it under `systemd` if you're familiar with that, or you could use `cron` if you want a simpler method:

From your user `pi` account, open `root` `crontab` for editing:

```bsh
$ sudo crontab -e
```

This **assumes** you actually need `sudo` privileges for something you do in your Python code; if you don't, then use `crontab -e` to get `pi` `crontab`.

Once the `crontab` is opened in the editor, add one line:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep/30; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mycodedir >> /home/pi/myoutput.txt 2>&1
```

Try this. If you have any questions about it before you try it, feel free to ask. If you try it, and it doesn't work, please add the relevant bits of `/home/pi/myoutput.txt` file to your question.

Comment: i tried using cron but still the same problem. code works but can't create files with data. i don't know if it will help but im using pickle to dump file. `myoutput.txt` gets created but is empty

Comment: @LongToeBoy: Add some `sleep` time (see revised answer) to see if it's a resource availability issue. If not, then you have some troubleshooting to do. I'd recommend starting with a "Hello World" app in Python - schedule the app to run in the `crontab` & verify it writes "hello world" to some file.